# How to send a generated csv file from node to another service provider?

Tags: node.js

**Requirement**

Based on client request using node I will fetch the data from database. The fetched  json value I convert it into csv. Then I need to send this csv file into another server. Which is not node

for creating the csv file I am using the below code

```
let headers = Object.keys(res.data[0])
const csvheader = { headers }
const csvparser = new Json2csvParser(csvheader)
const csv = csvparser.parse(res.data)
```

I tried like below. Using the **form-data** npm package. I am writing the csv file into 'mycsvfile.csv' and submitting the form. It does not gives any message

```
var form = new FormData({maxDataSize: 20971520});
form.append('fileName', "mycsvfile.csv");
form.append('files', fs.writeFileSync("mycsvfile.csv", csv));

form.submit({
  host: host,
  path:  path,
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log("Error",err);
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Please help a proper solution for submitting the csv file.